# Android Popupwindow doesn't update in correct position when keyboard is appearing API 26(Samsung S8)

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am facing popup window update issue in Samsung S8 device when keyboard is appearing. In my sample editText is placed bottom of the screen and popup window will be appear at top of that editText. But popup window does not appear in the correct position when editText get focused.(only in API 26). For all other devices it work as expected.

Replication steps:

1)Focus EditText (only S8 API 26)

2)change Text

3)Popup not appear above editText

Code

```
EditText editText; 
        PopupWindow popupWindow;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this){Orientation=Orientation.Vertical};

            editText = new EditText(this) { Text = "TestEditText" };
            editText.TextChanged+= EditText_TextChanged;
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
            relativeLayout.LayoutParameters = new Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            relativeLayout.AddView(editText);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(1000, 150);
            layoutParams.SetMargins(0, 1400, 0, 0);
            editText.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
            linearLayout.AddView(relativeLayout);

            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(this);
            LinearLayout linearLayoutnew = new LinearLayout(this);
            linearLayoutnew.AddView(new TextView(this) { Text = "Testing Popup window behavioor with S8 devices" });
            linearLayoutnew.AddView(new Button(this) { Text = "TestButton" });
            linearLayoutnew.LayoutParameters = new Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(300, 200);
            popupWindow.Height = 200;
            popupWindow.ContentView = linearLayoutnew;
            SetContentView(linearLayout);
        }

        void EditText_TextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            popupWindow.ShowAsDropDown(editText, 0, -(editText.Height + popupWindow.Height));
        }
```

Is there any workaround to solve this issue.

Comment: Any solution for this??

Comment: I faced the same issue recently on the same device, but when runnng Unity3D. I'd be more than happy to get some more insights here.